# Where to paste google analytics tracking id if firebase is used for hosting the website?

Tags: firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am setting my website to be advertised by google using google ads. In doing so I came across a section `Set up analytics on your website` there it showed two options out of which one is `Sign in to your website builder, web hosting service, or commerce platform and paste your tracking ID into the analytics section.`

I am using firebase hosting service for my website. So as mentioned I went to the analytics section of firebase but I am unable to understand where I have to paste the tracking id.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Firebase hosting, then you don't need to paste the tracking ID.
Just make sure you add a web app and link it with your current hosted application.

This might change overtime, but on the Firebase console, go to project settings, and scroll down till you see ***Your apps*** section. Add (if doesn't exists) a web app, and you should see a ***Linked Firebase Hosting site***

Once linked, Analytics will start tracking metrics for you.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of going to firebase, google analytics can do it for you just go to their website navigate to your website and copy the javascript code and paste it just below the head tag